# Reversing a string in C x86 error

Tags: c, string, x86

I am trying to do a simple strrev on a string and I keep getting this error when I compile it on my mac

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_strrev", referenced from:
  _main in cc1zSAum.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char str[] = "Hello world";
  char * test;
  test = strrev(str);
  printf("%s",test);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried playing around with the strrev line
but nothing is working

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard C function by that name. I did a little Googling and it looks like a few compilers and/or C library implementations have included such a function as a non-standard extension, but you can't expect any arbitrary library to have one.

Would be simple enough to write your own, though -- could be a one line loop body, even.

Comment: No, I didn't write one, I found strrev here http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..\html\book\Toolkt40\XPG4REF.INF+275

Comment: Puzzling comment Greg. "No" implies Ernest thinks you did write strrev() where as actually it is clear he knows you did not.

Comment: @BillForster I think before he edited his answer it was  was "There's no standard C function by that name, did you write your own?" That is what I commented on saying "No, I didn't ....."

Comment: @Greg, okay sorry about that.